# Is there a use for the Spectre card?

Tags: shantae-and-the-seven-sirens

It boosts Refresh Dance damage, but I remember nothing that can be damaged by the Refresh Dance, that can survive more than one use?

Or is that only in Definitive Mode?

Comment: Apparently in Definitive Mode enemies take more hits to be killed, but Refresh dance is OP by default so the game might be just unbalanced.